# Agrupar elementos de um arraylist com id semelhantes e somar seus valores Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho um arraylist que vem de um Banco de Dados e queria agrupar por exemplo quando seu código e data forem o mesmo.

Ex:

Original

```
{CODIGO=321, DESCRICAO=TESTE 123, DOCUMENTO=XPTO, VALOR=444.64, DATA-2022-03-01}
{CODIGO=321, DESCRICAO=TESTE 843, DOCUMENTO=DXY, VALOR=467.00, DATA-2022-03-01}
{CODIGO=322, DESCRICAO=TESTE 748, DOCUMENTO=CXQ, VALOR=43.01, DATA-2022-03-02}
{CODIGO=322, DESCRICAO=TESTE 748, DOCUMENTO=CXS, VALOR=53.01, DATA-2022-03-02}
{CODIGO=322, DESCRICAO=TESTE 4993, DOCUMENTO=VWXP, VALOR=103.3, DATA-2022-03-03}
```

Esperado (Importante é só que agrupe e some os valores)

```
{CODIGO=321, DESCRICAO= , DOCUMENTO= , VALOR=911.64,DATA-2022-03-01}
{CODIGO=322, DESCRICAO= , DOCUMENTO= , VALOR=96.02, DATA-2022-03-02}
{CODIGO=322, DESCRICAO= , DOCUMENTO= , VALOR=103.3, DATA-2022-03-03}
```

Consigo agrupar utilizando esse código:

```
lista.stream()
           .collect(collectingAndThen(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparing(MeuObjeto::getCodigo))), ArrayList::new));
```

Mas ele não soma, apenas remove os valores duplicados